# Using Frameset with Treeviews in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, frameset

Afternoon, I am trying have an HTML file containing a frameset which contains two frames. I have populated the left Frame with a URL containing a TreeView with URL's for the nodes.
I would like the to be able to select a URL from the treeview in the left hand frame, and have it set the src of the right hand frame to be that URL.
Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the "target" attribute on your links in the treeview to be the name of the "other" frame